# Update Element in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have problem with updating elements in arraylist. I have class `ViewLabelINScreen` and I build an arraylist of elements from this class, but when I update elements in this arraylist, with out another element in same object get value Default. How can I change only this element with out changeing other elements too.

I changed this element in different class which add this element and I need this array list static.

*ViewLabelINScreen:*

```
public class ViewLabelINScreen {
    public int xP;
    public int yP;
    public String nameLabel;
    public int stringWidth4;
    public int fontHeight;
    public boolean stored;

    public ViewLabelINScreen(int XP,int YP,String NameLabel,int StringWidth4 ,int FontHeight )
    {
        xP=XP; yP=YP; nameLabel=NameLabel;stringWidth4=StringWidth4;fontHeight=FontHeight;
    }

    //this contractor for change namelabel
    public ViewLabelINScreen (String Namelabel)
    {
        nameLabel=Namelabel;
    }

    public ViewLabelINScreen () {

    }    
}
```

The following class adds the element into the arraylist.

```
public class WgsGrid {
    //Added by A.B
    MapSelection mapSelection;
    public static ArrayList<ViewLabelINScreen> INFOLable = new ArrayList<ViewLabelINScreen>();
    for (int i4 = hMin; i4 <= hMax; i4++)
    {
        INFOLable.add(new ViewLabelINScreen(labelRectX, labelRectY - yOffset4, SetLabels.getYlabels()[counter2],stringWidth4,fontHeight));
    }
}
```

This class *NeedChangeArrayList* change an element:

```
class NeedChangeArrayList {
    public void ChangeAraay()
    {
        if (WgsGrid.INFOLable.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < ylabels.length; s++)
            {
                WgsGrid.INFOLable.set(s, new ViewLabelINScreen(ylabels[s]));
            }

            //ylabels[s] string array get value from array and put in nameLabel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you instantiate a `WgsGrid` object?

Comment: yes I instantiate  WgsGrid when start program, when put all element inside arraylist.

Comment: other time when user click button,program call "ChangeAraay" for update element namelabel which content inside arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you changing all the nameLabel values in the array list? If so, you can try this in your for loop:

```
for(int s =0; s< WgsGrid.INFOLable.size();s++){
    WgsGrid.INFOLable.get(s).setNameLabel("whatever");
}
```

You need to create a setter method for nameLabel though.

```
public void setNameLabel(String nameLabel){
    this.nameLabel = nameLabel;
}
```

(I've changed from ylabels.length to the arraylist's size. Not sure what you were doing with ylabels)